# Dokku app supposed to point to subdomain instead points to domain of other app

Tags: nginx, subdomain, dokku

I am trying to host a new app on a subdomain on an existing Dokku instance but it seems to point to the domain of another app altogether.

I have a multiple domains with DNS records managed via Cloudflare.

I have one A record for `aaa.com`:

```
A aaa.com <vps-ip>
```

And two A records for `bbb.com`:

```
A bbb.com <vps-ip>
A *.bbb.com <vps-ip>
```

When I run `dokku apps:list` I get:

```
=====> My Apps
aaa
newapp
```

(while my app names are different, their lexicographical order follows the above)

When I run `dokku domains:report` I get:

```
=====> newapp domains information
       Domains app enabled:           true
       Domains app vhosts:            newapp.bbb.com
       Domains global enabled:        true
       Domains global vhosts:         bbb.com
=====> aaa domains information
       Domains app enabled:           true
       Domains app vhosts:            aaa.com
       Domains global enabled:        true
       Domains global vhosts:         bbb.com
```

If I run `dokku domains:report newapp`, `bbb.com` is also listed as as a vhost.

I have verified that the DNS records are updated. I have also verified that the server that is supposed to power `newapp.bbb.com` is running by `dokku enter`ing and `curl`ing locally.

When I send HTTP requests to e.g. `newapp.bbb.com/endpoint`, the contents of `aaa.com` are returned. Similarly, if I just query `bbb.com` I also get the contents of `aaa.com`.

I have surely misconfigured something but I cannot figure out what's heads and what's tails. I have dug around the official Dokku docs as well as various SO posts without any luck.

I am guessing that I am lacking nginx insights so I would greatly appreciate any pointers.